# Obtain duration when certain variable value InfluxQL

Tags: sql, influxdb, influxql

I am using InfluxQL language to extract data from InfluxDB. I want to get the duration when I have a variable with True value.

I have this on my database:

time running

2022-09-16 09:00:00  False

2022-09-16 09:05:00  False

2022-09-16 09:10:00  True

2022-09-16 09:40:00  True

2022-09-16 10:00:00  False

2022-09-16 12:00:00  True

2022-09-16 12:10:00  False

I want to get this result:

**Duration True: 1h**

1h = 50 min (09:10-10:00) + 10 min (12:00-12:10)

Can someone give me an advice with an InfluxQL query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is feasible to report the total duration for a given state in InfluxDB but only in Flux not InfluxQL (easily).
You could try following steps:

1. Enable Flux in v1.8 with the configuration change [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/installation/)
2. Sample Flux could be:

   from(bucket: "yourDatabaseName/autogen") |> range(start: 2022-09-16T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-16T23:59:59Z) |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "yourMeasurementName")  |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == true, column: "state", unit: 1m)

Again it's still not possible to do it yet in InfluxQL though the community has been waiting for this for a while. See more details [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7581).